# Как лучше всего организовать структуру C++ проекта, использующего CMake и юнит-тесты?

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, тестирование, cmake

Как лучше всего организовать структуру C++ проекта, использующего CMake и юнит-тесты?

Искал примеры в интернете - в основном все тесты пихают в отдельную директорию test. Для каждого XXX.cpp файла проекта создаётся test_XXX.cpp с тестом функциональности этих файлов. Хороший ли это подход, ведь происходит дублирование по сути? Как организовать это в CMake? Если делать в лоб (1 executable для приложения, 1 - для тестов), то компиляция будет в 2 раза дольше... Планируется писать юнит-тесты для функционала и производительности. Надо ли как-то обособлять их или в одном файле ок?

Comment: Непонятно, чем вас так смущает необходимость отдельного приложения для юнит-тестов? Как вы себе представляете приложение со встроенными юнит-тестами? Юнит-тесты для функционала - это функциональные тесты, юнит тесты для производительности - это тесты производительности. Что касается cmake, то без него можно прекрасно обойтись.

Comment: @VTT тем что 1) для каждого файла вручную надо создавать файл тестов 2) файлов в 2 раза больше => компиляция в 2 раза дольше. Если можно как-то избежать этих проблем, оставив 2 приложения, то ок

Comment: «файлов в 2 раза больше => компиляция в 2 раза дольше» — это не так. Подход с разделением проектов на основной и тестовый является наиболее популярным и удобным. Есть и другие варианты, но они маргинальные.